# passing different array variables to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In a controller I have defined two different arrays and I need to pass different arrays to directives, but the same item array is getting passed only.

Actually this is just snippets. In my actual code this directive I am using inside another.

Is that causing problem or any other way?

```
<div my-sticky tags="items" template_name="test2.html"></div>
<div my-sticky tags="kititems" template_name="test2.html"></div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.items = [
            { id: 18, text: '1' },
            { id: 28, text: '2' },
            { id: 38, text: '3' }
        ];
    $scope.kititems = [
            { id: 0, text: '001' },
            { id: 028, text: '002' },
            { id: 038, text: '003' }
        ];
});

app.directive("mySticky", function($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        scope : {
            templateName: "@",
            tags: "=",
        },
        templateUrl : function(el, attrs) {
            return attrs.templateName;
        },
        controller : function($http, $scope, $element, $sce, $templateCache, $compile, $attrs) {

            $scope.drawerStyle = {left: '140px'};

            //$scope.CommonArray=$attrs.tags;

        },
        replace : false,
        transclude : false,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // change element just to show we can
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Probably an error in the templates (using same scope variable). Show us templates.

Comment: Do you experience the issue with the code you are showing? Seems to work for me.

Comment: @tasseKATT yes that array variable is undefined m getting ? whr did u tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pb2XE/)

Inside your templateURL(test2.html) should like this i.e,

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in tags"> {{tag.id}} {{tag.text}} </div>
```

You might try to access `items or kititems` both are not in current scope because you have used isolated scope here.For clarity template used here instead of templateURL.

HTML Markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   MyCtrl
<div my-sticky tags="items"></div>
    <hr/>
<div my-sticky tags="kititems"></div> 
 </div>
```

angular modules

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
            { id: 18, text: '1' },
            { id: 28, text: '2' },
            { id: 38, text: '3' }
        ];
    $scope.kititems = [
            { id: 0, text: '001' },
            { id: 028, text: '002' },
            { id: 038, text: '003' }
        ];
});

app.directive("mySticky", function($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        scope : {
            templateName: "@",
            tags: "=",
        },
        template :'<div ng-repeat="tag in tags"> {{tag.id}} {{tag.text}} </div>',
        controller : function($http, $scope, $element, $sce, $templateCache, $compile, $attrs) {

            $scope.drawerStyle = {left: '140px'};

           // console.log($scope);
            //$scope.CommonArray=$attrs.tags;

        },
        replace : false,
        transclude : false,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // change element just to show we can
        }
    };
});
```